# PDO--why this code can't connect the database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
         <?php
 $host = 'localhost';
 $db='mysql';
  $user = 'root';
 $pass = 123;
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
  if($conn){
echo 'ok';
  }else {
 echo 'error';
  }
    ?>
```

why this code can't connect the database? my php.ini file setting is right,

> extension=php_pdo.dll

extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

the database user is root, the password is 123. thank you

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Comment: you must enable mysql pdo driver

Comment: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll, i have commentted this line in the php.ini, why it still can't work?

Comment: If you're running Apache/mod_php, don't forget you need to restart Apache after changing PHP ini settings before they'll take effect.

Comment: And check your log for Extension loading Problems for the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are at the beginning of a project and are unable to make PDO work, you might be able to have more luck with mySQLi.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php